# Highcharts. How do I add a custom scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[image with example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gev5h.png)

On the top of image is embedded scrollbar with navigator, but i need to create scrollbar with custom elements - scrollbar on the bottom of image.

I need scroll and resize a graph with it.

How can i do this?

UPD: **markup**

```
<div class="chart-box">

    <div id="chart-pane">
        <div id="chart-pays">
            <div class="chart-canvas">
                <!-- place for graph -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- my custom scrollbar -->
    <div id="chart-scrollbar">
        <div class="handler ui-draggable ui-resizable">
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can customize high chart scroll bar

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
 scrollbar: {
                barBackgroundColor: 'gray',
                barBorderRadius: 7,
                barBorderWidth: 0,
                buttonBackgroundColor: 'gray',
                buttonBorderWidth: 0,
                buttonBorderRadius: 7,
                trackBackgroundColor: 'none',
                trackBorderWidth: 1,
                trackBorderRadius: 8,
                trackBorderColor: '#CCC'
            },
}
```

[refer here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/styled-scrollbar/)

Comment: Thanks, but this variant does not fit.
In description i wrote, that i need to create a custom element.
Main target - resize a graph.

Comment: pls refer here http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts , or show us some codes that you have tried already